# Секундомер слишком медленный, в чём проблема?

Tags: android, kotlin, countdowntimer

У меня есть объект CountDownTimer, имеющий интервал в 10 миллисекунд.
Я делал что-то вроде секундомера, который отображает значение миллисекунд в сотнях и десятках, то есть вместо 260 миллисекунд, он показывает 26, и по логике вещей каждые 10 миллисекунд значение должно было увеличиваться на 1: 27, 28, 29 и так далее.
Но в итоге секундомер получился медленным, вот моё решение:

```
val timer = object : CountDownTimer(86400000, 10) {
                override fun onTick(millisUntilFinished: Long) {
                    val h = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.hoursnumber)
                    val m = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.minutesnumber)
                    val s = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.secondsnumber)
                    val ms = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.milisecondsnumber)
                    if (indexMiliseconds == 99) {
                        if (indexSeconds == 59) {
                            if (indexMinutes == 59) {
                                indexHours++
                                indexMinutes = 0
                                indexMiliseconds = 0
                            } else {
                                indexMinutes++
                                indexSeconds = 0
                                indexMiliseconds = 0
                            }
                        } else {
                            indexSeconds++
                            indexMiliseconds = 0
                        }
                    }
                    indexMiliseconds += 1
                    ms.text = miliSeconds[indexMiliseconds]
                    s.text = seconds[indexSeconds]
                    m.text = minutes[indexMinutes]
                    h.text = hours[indexHours]
                }
                override fun onFinish() {
                    indexMinutes = 0
                    indexHours = 0
                    indexSeconds = 0
                    indexMiliseconds = 0
                    val h = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.hoursnumber)
                    val m = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.minutesnumber)
                    val s = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.secondsnumber)
                    val ms = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.milisecondsnumber)
                    ms.text = miliSeconds[indexMiliseconds]
                    s.text = seconds[indexSeconds]
                    m.text = minutes[indexMinutes]
                    h.text = hours[indexHours]
                }
            }.start()
```

````
private val hours: List<String> = listOf(
        "00", "01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06", "07", "08", "09", "10", "11", "12",
        "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23"
    )
    private var indexHours = 0

    private val minutes: List<String> = listOf(
        "00", "01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06", "07", "08",
        "09", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22",
        "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "31", "32", "33", "34", "35", "36",
        "37", "38", "39", "40", "41", "42", "43", "44", "45", "46", "47", "48", "49",
        "50", "51", "52", "53", "54", "55", "56", "57", "58", "59", "60"
    )
    private var indexMinutes = 0

    private val seconds: List<String> = listOf(
        "00", "01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06", "07", "08",
        "09", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22",
        "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "31", "32", "33", "34", "35", "36",
        "37", "38", "39", "40", "41", "42", "43", "44", "45", "46", "47", "48", "49",
        "50", "51", "52", "53", "54", "55", "56", "57", "58", "59", "60"
    )
    private var indexSeconds = 0

    private val miliSeconds: List<String> = listOf(
        "00",
        "01",
        "02",
        "03",
        "04",
        "05",
        "06",
        "07",
        "08",
        "09",
        "10",
        "11",
        "12",
        "13",
        "14",
        "15",
        "16",
        "17",
        "18",
        "19",
        "20",
        "21",
        "22",
        "23",
        "24",
        "25",
        "26",
        "27",
        "28",
        "29",
        "30",
        "31",
        "32",
        "33",
        "34",
        "35",
        "36",
        "37",
        "38",
        "39",
        "40",
        "41",
        "42",
        "43",
        "44",
        "45",
        "46",
        "47",
        "48",
        "49",
        "50",
        "51",
        "52",
        "53",
        "54",
        "55",
        "56",
        "57",
        "58",
        "59",
        "60",
        "61",
        "62",
        "63",
        "64",
        "65",
        "66",
        "67",
        "68",
        "69",
        "70",
        "71",
        "72",
        "73",
        "74",
        "75",
        "76",
        "77",
        "78",
        "79",
        "80",
        "81",
        "82",
        "83",
        "84",
        "85",
        "86",
        "87",
        "88",
        "89",
        "90",
        "91",
        "92",
        "93",
        "94",
        "95",
        "96",
        "97",
        "98",
        "99",
        "100"
    )
    private var indexMiliseconds = 0```
````

Comment: Зачем же вы каждые 10мс по дереву UI ищете одни и те же 4 контрола? Вот  оно и тормозит все у вас. Оптимизируйте. Профайлер вам в помощь: https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/android-profiler

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja не помогло, всё равно медленный.